# How to disable statusbar and navigationbar animation when activating/deactivating full-screen mode in Android

Tags: android, animation, statusbar, navigationbar

**Problem**

Activating and Deactivating [(immersive) full-screen mode](https://developer.android.com/training/system-ui/immersive) causes that the statusbar but also navigation bar "fades" in and out. The animation seem to differ across different devices and I would like to disable the animation completely. My minimum target SDK is 19; however, I would also be happy with a solution that requires a higher API level. Please see below for further details.

**Running demo**

I implemented a (minimal) demo so that people can test things easily. Everything is available on GitHub:

- https://github.com/sztyler/android-fullscreendemo

For clarification, I am using `setSystemUiVisibility(FLAGS)` to activate/deactivate the full screen mode. Further, I am using the following flags:

Activating full-screen mode:

```
int visibility = View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
                   | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                   | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN
                   | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY;
mainView.setSystemUiVisibility(visibility);
```

Deactivating full-screen mode:

```
int visibility = View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_VISIBLE;
mainView.setSystemUiVisibility(visibility);
```

**What I tried**

I already tried many different things and did a lot of research. In the following, I want summaries the main approaches which I already tried.

1. Instead of using `setSystemUiVisibility` (which seems to be recommended) a lot of people recommend to use `getWindow().setFlags` to change flags. However, setting the Flags in a different way does not seem to have an effect. I also assume that this is outdated.

- [how to remove statusbar animation when changing to fullscreen in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9312029/how-to-remove-statusbar-animation-when-changing-to-fullscreen-in-android)
- [Hide and show statusBar with Toolbar at the same time in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38189152/hide-and-show-statusbar-with-toolbar-at-the-same-time-in-android)
- [Android: Disable and enable to pulling the status bar programmatically for API 19](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48782715/android-disable-and-enable-to-pulling-the-status-bar-programmatically-for-api-1)
- [hide and show statusbar without any effect to layout in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27224106/hide-and-show-statusbar-without-any-effect-to-layout-in-android)
- [Android: show/hide status bar/power bar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8273186/android-show-hide-status-bar-power-bar)

2. It seems to be possible to exclude the status bar and navigation bar from the exit/enter fade transition when switching between activities. However, this does not seem to have any effect on activating/deactivating full-screen mode.

- [How do I prevent the status bar and navigation bar from animating during an activity scene animation transition?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26600263/how-do-i-prevent-the-status-bar-and-navigation-bar-from-animating-during-an-acti)

3. Some people just recommend different flags (just in general to hide the bars) -but the animation stays the same.

   `View.setSystemUiVisibility(View.STATUS_BAR_HIDDEN);`

- [Android: Ability to Auto-Hide the Title/Status Bars?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4904013/android-ability-to-auto-hide-the-title-status-bars)

4. Some people highlight that it is possible to override the subsequent animation with `overridePendingTransition(0, 0)`
   but this does not seem so work in this case.

- [Is there any way to remove notification/status bar, but not in onCreate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8792101/is-there-any-way-to-remove-notification-status-bar-but-not-in-oncreate)

**How the animation can look like**

Just to clarify what I mean.  In the following, there are gif animations which show the status/navigation bar animation (Sorry I don't have the permission to embed images)

Android 8.0 / Huawei / There is no fade out animation (both bars just vanish as required but there is a fade in animation). Both statusbar and navigationbar "flash in".

- [Statusbar Animation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DEQbX.gif)
- [Navigationbar Animation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MOWnH.gif)

Android 5.0 / Samsung / There is a fade in and fade out animation (There is no navigationbar).

- [Statusbar Animation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GAq1X.gif)

(The behavior of the actionbar is as expected.)

Comment: I also want to redefine status bar animation when show status bar. 
Did you fix your issue. could you point me where it is. Thank you so much

Comment: sorry but I never solved this problem :/